# What does this ASP.NET web.config error mean?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-config

I have a simple asp.net project. I put it on my host but I now have the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as   
allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can 
be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 

  Line 37:     ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
  Line 38:     -->
  Line 39:     <authentication mode="Windows" />
  Line 40:     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  Line 41:       <pages>
```

[LINK](http://sarafandnet.com/kaka/Default.aspx)

Comment: May be you two web.config files.Try to remove which s not needed.

Comment: Have you configured its published directory as an application?  (In IIS)

Comment: Configure all MachineToApplication settings in your application's root,
and remove all MachineToApplication settings from your application's
subdirectories.

Comment: there is only oe i the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error, but got resolved by changing the app pool..try changing the app pool..as such i changed it from default app pool to classic .net app pool.
Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Create the virtual directory for it on the server - like the error message says.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is because you have not configured IIS to treat this directory as an application.

I'm assuming you published under the inetpub\wwwroot path on the host.

On the host, in IIS (Internet Information Services - Under Administrative Tools in the Control Panel).  You need to navigate to the directory you published under (Default Web Site[your path].

Right click the directory and choose Add Application (on IIS 7+) ([Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28WS.10%29.aspx)) or Properties and then click the button that says "Create" by the Application Name field near the bottom ([image](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davidbi/IIS-CreateApp_ijLM1A.jpg))

Comment: Command Line Tool: appcmd add app /site.name: string /path: string /physicalPath: string

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link and here is the workaround for this http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37609.aspx

Try changing `< authentication mode="None" />`